# Converting CGFloat to NSUInteger returns 0

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm converting this `CGFloat`:

```
CGFloat verticalTranslation = CGFLOAT_MAX;
```

... to `NSUInteger` using the following code:

```
if (verticalTranslation > NSUIntegerMax) unsignedInteger = NSUIntegerMax;
else unsignedInteger = verticalTranslation;
```

It works. However, as soon as I replace `if` with ternary operator, `unsignedInteger` becomes `0`:

```
NSUInteger unsignedInteger = verticalTranslation > NSUIntegerMax ? NSUIntegerMax : verticalTranslation;
```

Why does `unsignedInteger` equal `0` and not `NSUIntegerMax` when using the ternary version?

Comment: I suspect you may need to explicitly cast verticalTranslation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you try:

```
NSUInteger unsignedInteger = verticalTranslation > NSUIntegerMax ? NSUIntegerMax : (NSUInteger)verticalTranslation;
```

Comment: -1 `NSUInteger` isn't the same as `int`, so your newly casted int might overflow and be something strange.

Comment: @JustSid: I don't believe there is any way for NSUInteger to have a smaller range than int. Am I forgetting something?